# Adding thumbnails to bottom of page in drupal 7

Tags: views

I'm trying to add a bunch of thumbnails to the bottom of my page (footer or page bottom), the thumbnails come from article posts, or even forum posts.

I have enabled views, and set it up as a block at the bottom of the page. When I preview the view on admin/structure/views/view/thumbnails3/edit/block%3Fdestination%3Dnode it displays the thumbnails how I want, but on the actual page it displays the title without thumbnails.

I'm using Drupal 7, and I have created a Zen sub-theme. Also, this is just locally on my computer using xampp at this stage.

Why doesn't the page show the thumbnails?

Comment: Did you save the view? Sorrs if this is dump questin, but I'm missing this step myself sometimes.

Comment: Have you tried to assign the block in some other inner page? It might be wrong with CSS design. You would write any display none for common img tag, id, or class.